# sqlite3 unable to select column from table in attached database

Tags: sqlite

I'm merging two similar databases (A and B) where I take entries in A that aren't in B and add them to B. I was trying to do it with an attached database (I used .open A.db and attach 'B.db' as B). Both have table C which contains column D. I need to do some inner joins on other tables, but first I need to do something like:

```
select D from C where not exists (select D from B.C where C.D = B.C.D);
```

And I get the error "no such column: B.C.D

Are you not allowed two dots in one expression? Do I need to somehow use "as" to fix that, or would that even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 2 tables contain a column `D` then you should not get that error.

But, there is another problem in the subquery:

```
select D from B.C where C.D = B.C.D
```

`C.D` is interpreted as the column `D` of the table `B.C` and not the table `A.C` as you might expect.

Set an alias for the table `A.C` and use it inside the subquery:

```
select D from C AS x where not exists (select D from B.C where x.D = B.C.D);
```

Or, use `EXCEPT`:

```
select D from C 
EXCEPT
select D from B.C
```

Answer (score -1):

Use quotes around those items that have dots in them

```
select D from C where not exists (select D from "B.C" where C.D = "B.C.D");
```

There is one question - where is the table "B"  in your clause?

Comment: This will throw the error: "no such table: B.C" because everything between the double quotes will be considered as the table's name.